# Python prime listing repetition bug

Tags: python, python-3.x, primes

Trying to create a program that lists the prime numbers in a set interval (has to be between 1 and 500), so user input isnt allowed. This is my code so far:

```
list=[]
for num in range(1, 500):
    if num > 1:
        for i in range(2, num):
            if (num % i) == 0:
                break
            else:
                list.append(str(num))
print(','.join(list))
```

However, when I run this code some of the primes are repeated multiple times in the list, making it much longer than it should be. How can i fix this? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: The problem is that until you find a number `i` that divides `num`, `num` is added to the list. It is straightforward that you will have each prime in the list many times. In fact if `n` is prime, you will have `n` in the list `n-2` times. You will also have all odd numbers in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You only want to add the number to the list of primes *after* you've checked all the possible divisors.  That means you only add it after the `for` loop has completed.

A good way to do this is with the optional [`else` clause on `for` loops](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops).

> Loop statements may have an `else` clause; it is executed when the loop
>   terminates through exhaustion of the list (with `for`) or when the
>   condition becomes false (with `while`), but not when the loop is
>   terminated by a `break` statement.

You can improve this function by only checking the modulus of primes you've already found.  Since all non-prime numbers have prime roots, you only need to check if a number is divisible by lesser primes to determine if it is a prime.

```
primes = []
for i in range(2, 501):
    for p in primes:
        if i % p == 0:
            break
    else:
        primes.append(i)
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped me understand it much better

Answer (score -1):

In the loop:

```
for i in range(2, num):
    if (num % i) == 0:
        break
    else:
        list.append(str(num))
```

you are appending the prime once for every `i`. The `else` should line up with the `for`:

```
for i in range(2, num):
    if (num % i) == 0:
        break
else:   # note: different indentation!
    list.append(str(num))
```

In python loops can have an `else` clause which is executed only if no `break` was executed inside the loop. They can be used to avoid boolean flags in a lot of cases.

So the code:

```
found = False
for x in iterator:
    if predicate(x):
        found = True
        break

if not found:
    # do default action
```

can be replaced by:

```
for x in iterator:
    if predicate(x):
        break
else:
    #do default action
```

Comment: The else for the loop is a good thing that I did not know. Something to make sure though is that the OP toes not want to include `1`. In this case, he must exclude 1 from the external loop, which was redundant anyway.

Comment: @innoSPG OP's code already contains an `if num > 1` so `1` wont be checked at all.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you are adding each only once.
The problem is that until you find a number `i` that divides `num`, `num` is added to the list. It is straightforward that you will have each prime in the list many times. In fact if `n` is prime, you will have `n` in the list `n-2` times. You will also have all odd numbers in the list.
Only even numbers won't appear in the list, because the first number against which you are testing the divisibility is `2` and `2` divides all even numbers.

Without changing too much in your algorithm, you can introduce a flag `isPrime` that is set to `True` by default, and whenever you find `i` that divides `num` you set `isPrime` to `True` before breaking the loop. Your program becomes:

```
list=[]
for num in range(1, 500):
    if num > 1:
        isPrime=True
        for i in range(2, num):
            if (num % i) == 0:
                isPrime = False
                break
        if isPrime:
            list.append(str(num))
print(','.join(list))
```